# Как зафиксировать объект на другом объекте, который находится в движении?

Tags: unity3d

Я делаю симулятор доставки еды и при переносе предмета на машину - предмет падает во время её движения. Как зафиксировать его на определенной плоскости, чтобы предмет тоже перемещался с машиной?

Comment: Как вариант навскидку: после переноса предмета на машину, у его компонента ригидбади выстави isKinematic в true, а сам предмет сделай дочерним к машине.

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант: у машины должен быть триггер, который проверял бы попадание в себя другого коллайдера (например с тэгом "pizza") и по событию OnTriggerEnter, выдавал объекту Pizza текущие координаты машины с поправкой на координаты пиццы, где на машине она должна находиться. Далее, по событию OnTriggerStay, объект Pizza менял бы свои координаты в соответствии с координатами машины и поправкой.  После доставки, при попадании коллайдера пиццы в триггер места доставки, объект Pizza уничтожается и начисляются очки или кредиты. Ну и не забывать при этом установку флажка IsKinematic у пиццы перед получением её машиной.